# iOS (iPhone/iPad) SDK - UITableView not refreshing on reloadData (numberOfSectionsInTableView etc. does not get called on reloadData)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

For some reason `[tView reloadData]` (where tView is a UITableView) does not refresh my UITableView. `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` only get called once - at load. Those methods don't seem to be called after `[tView reloadData]`. Here's my code:

(AppDelegate.h):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

@class FirstNavViewController;
@class SecondTableViewController;

@interface <appname>AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, MBProgressHUDDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *rootController;
    FirstNavViewController *viewController;
    SecondTableViewController *viewController1;
    NSMutableData *responseData;
    NSMutableArray *blogEntries;
    MBProgressHUD *HUD;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *rootController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet FirstNavViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet SecondTableViewController *viewController1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *blogEntries;
@end
```

(AppDelegate.m):

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "FirstNavViewController.h"
#import "SecondTableViewController.h"
#import "SBJson.h"
#define TMP NSTemporaryDirectory()

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize rootController;
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize viewController1;
@synthesize blogEntries;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    CGFloat width = self.rootController.view.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.rootController.view.bounds.size.height;
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height)];
    UIImage *imageView = [UIImage imageNamed:@"theme_frame.png"];
    UIColor *kMainColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:imageView];

    [v setBackgroundColor:kMainColor];
    [kMainColor release];
    [self.rootController.tabBar insertSubview:v atIndex:0];
    imageView = nil;
    [v release];

    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    blogEntries = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                             [NSURL URLWithString:@"ENTER_JSON_URL_HERE"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    NSAssert(nil != self.rootController, @"tab bar controller not hooked up!");

    BOOL iPad = NO;
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
    iPad = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
#endif

    if (iPad) {
        self.viewController = [[[FirstNavViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstNavViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        self.viewController1 = [[[SecondTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondTableViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
    else {
        self.viewController = [[[FirstNavViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstNavViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        self.viewController1 = [[[SecondTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondTableViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }

    self.rootController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.viewController];

    self.rootController.selectedIndex = 0;

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_4_0
    self.window.rootViewController = self.rootController;
#else
    [self.window addSubview:rootController.view];
#endif

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:viewController.view];
    [viewController.view addSubview:HUD];
    [HUD show:NO];

    // Regisete for HUD callbacks so we can remove it from the window at the right time
    HUD.delegate = self;

    HUD.labelText = @"Loading";

    return YES;
}

#pragma mark NSURLConnection delegate methods
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [HUD hide:YES];
    [connection release];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseData release];

    NSMutableArray *allBlogEntries = [responseString JSONValue];
    [viewController1 setBlogEntries:allBlogEntries];
    [responseString release];
    [HUD hide:YES];

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [rootController release];
    [viewController release];
    [viewController1 release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

(FirstNavViewController.h):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstNavViewController : UIViewController {
    UINavigationController *navController;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navController;
@end
```

(FirstNavViewController.m):

```
#import "FirstNavViewController.h"
#import "SecondTableViewController.h"

@implementation FirstNavViewController

@synthesize navController;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [self tabBarItem];
        UIImage *tabBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blog.png"];
        [tabBarItem setImage:tabBarImage];
        [tabBarItem setTitle:@"Blog"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
    SecondTableViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BlogOverviewViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    [navController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:NO];
    [blogOverviewViewController release];
    [self.view addSubview:navController.view];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

(SecondTableViewController.h):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SBJson.h"

@interface SecondTableViewController : UIViewController {
    NSMutableArray *blogEntries;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *blogEntries;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arryData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tView;
@end
```

(SecondTableViewController.m):

```
#import "SecondTableViewController.h"
#import "ThirdDetailViewController.h"
#import "NSString+HTML.h"

NSString *convertedString;

@implementation SecondTableViewController

@synthesize arryData;
@synthesize tView;


-(NSMutableArray*)blogEntries {
    return [[blogEntries retain] autorelease];
}

-(void)setBlogEntries:(NSMutableArray*)newBlogEntries {
    if(newBlogEntries != blogEntries) {
        [newBlogEntries retain];

        [blogEntries release];
        blogEntries = newBlogEntries;

        [tView reloadData];
    }
}

#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [blogEntries count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    NSDictionary *aBlogEntry = [blogEntries objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSArray *bPosts = (NSArray *)[aBlogEntry objectForKey:@"posts"];

    NSString *stringToConvert = [bPosts valueForKey:@"title_plain"];
    NSString *convertedString = [stringToConvert stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];

    cell.textLabel.text = convertedString;
    cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    cell.textLabel.minimumFontSize = 10;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 4;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

    NSString *stringToConvert1 = [bPosts valueForKey:@"excerpt"];
    NSString *convertedString1 = [stringToConvert1 stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = convertedString1;

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ThirdDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[ThirdDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BlogContentViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    NSDictionary *aBlogEntry = [blogEntries objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSArray *bPosts = (NSArray *)[aBlogEntry objectForKey:@"posts"];

    NSString *stringToConvert = [bPosts valueForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *convertedString = [stringToConvert stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];

    [contentViewController changeTitleTextLabel:convertedString];

    NSString *stringToConvert1 = [bPosts valueForKey:@"content"];
    NSString *convertedString1 = [stringToConvert1 stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];

    NSString *newConvertedString1 = [convertedString1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\n" withString:@"\n\n"];

    [detailViewController changeContentTextLabel:newConvertedString1];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath animated: YES];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    blogEntries = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.title = @"Blog";
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [blogEntries release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? I am stuck on why the UITableView will not reloadData.

**EDIT:** Small background: I am using a UITabBarController (AppDelegate) with a UIViewController in it with a UINavigationController as a subview of that UIViewController (FirstNavViewController). The UINavigationController then has a subview with another UIViewController in it. The latter UIViewController (SecondTableViewController) includes a UITableView.

Answer (score 3):

I've just been having this issue. Turned out to be a threading problem for me. For those those who end up here after a search, here is my quick fix:

```
[tView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) 
                        withObject:nil
                     waitUntilDone:false];
```

It seems reloadData needs to be called on the main thread. I hope this helps (^_^)

Answer (score 1):

In your `viewDidLoad` method, add: `tView.delegate = self;`

Comment: Thank for your answer but the table view still doesn't reload data.

Comment: @Abizern - Am I? I though I was using UIViewController with a UITableView in it. Either way, I had connected up the delegate and datasource in IB.

Comment: Are you sure that your method is not getting called? Have you set breakpoints?

Comment: Yep. - my mistake. Do what Dylan says and put breakpoints in the parts that call reload data and follow through.

Comment: @Dylan Reich - I am pretty sure. I added NSLogs to the beginning of `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` and they're only executed once each - at load. (`cellForRowAtIndexPath` never called because `[blogEntries count]` was zero at load and caused the number of rows to be zero. That is why I need to be able to call `[tView reloadData];`).

Comment: I meant, add a breakpoint at the line where you call `reloadData`. If you don't know how to use breakpoints, add a line right after it; something like: `NSLog(@"reloadData has been called");`

Comment: @Dylan Reich - Okay, it does stop at the breakpoint on reloadData and the NSLog after reloadData does get called - but does that mean the reloadData is doing it's job? It still doesn't seam to refresh the UITableView.

Comment: Yes, if it is gettings called, it is doing it's job, unless there's something that I'm missing. Your problem may lie elsewhere.

Comment: Why are you returning [[blogEntries retain] autorelease] in your blogEntries getter? Does the table literally not refresh (i.e. old data is still shown) or does it refresh and show nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Your view setup might be the cause of your problems.

I don't really understand the details of your implementation but right now you are adding that SecondTableViewController to both the tab bar controller and then on the stack of a navigation controller in your FistNavViewController `viewDidLoad` method.

Create the navigation controller with `FistNavViewController` as its `rootViewController`, then add the navigation controller as the first view controller to your `UITabBarViewController`

(code here is typed from memory so please excuse any typos)

```
FirstNavViewController *vc = [[FirstNavViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nibname" andBundleName:nil];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
UITabBarController *tbc = [UITabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nc, otherVc1Example, otherVc2Example, nil] animated:NO];
```

In your `FirstNavViewController viewDidLoad` method, you can then instantiate `SecondTableViewController` and push it onto the stack with

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondTableViewController animated:YES];
```

Finally, within that nav controller you need to make sure you have your UITableView setup correcly either in Interface Builder (by connecting the datasource and delegate outlets to the file owner) or in code by manually setting the tableview delegate and datasource to self.

Bottom line is everything you are trying to do above is WAY easier and less error prone if you use Interface Builder. In MainWindow.xib simple add a tab bar controller and under it add navigation controllers and view controllers as you see fit. It should work "pretty much" out of the box.

Good luck.
Rog